# How to get versions of a certain project via verison bundle

Tags: java, api, youtrack

Since youtrack updated their api many requests have changed, so changed the version bundle request that i used usind previous api, it was quite easy to get versions of project with:

```
https://youtrack.protei.ru/rest/admin/customfield/versionBundle/%versionName%
```

new request should look something like this:

```
https://youtrack.protei.ru/api/admin/customFieldSettings/bundles/version?fields=name,values(id,name)
```

but is seems like i cannot use /%versionName% anymoe so the only way i can get a bundle for certain project is using project id in yt database, so i need to make 2 requests instead of one, maybe there is a way to search for specific version bundle in the new api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to make only one request to achieve that: you may either [operate](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/operations-api-admin-customFieldSettings-bundles-version.html) with a particular versionBundle [obtained](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/resource-api-admin-customFieldSettings-bundles-version.html) from the main list or do similar things but via [operating](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/resource-api-admin-projects-projectID-customFields.html) with the project's custom fields.